# Python Hough Lines implementation, making it time efficient

Tags: python, image-processing, hough-transform, houghlines

So I'm trying to implement the hough transform lines algorithm in python, and I'm finding it hard to make it time efficient.

This is my implementation:

```
import numpy as np
def houghLines(edges, dTheta, threshold):
    imageShape = edges.shape
    imageDiameter = (imageShape[0]**2 + imageShape[1]**2)**0.5
    rhoRange = [i for i in range(int(imageDiameter)+1)]
    thetaRange = [dTheta*i for i in range(int(-np.pi/(2*dTheta)), int(np.pi/dTheta))]
    cosTheta = [np.cos(theta) for theta in thetaRange]
    sinTheta = [np.sin(theta) for theta in thetaRange]
    countMatrix = np.zeros([len(rhoRange), len(thetaRange)])
    eds = [(x,y) for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(edges) if value > 0]
    for thetaIndex in range(len(thetaRange)):
        theta = thetaRange[thetaIndex]
        cos = cosTheta[thetaIndex]
        sin = sinTheta[thetaIndex]
        for x, y in eds:
            targetRho = x*cos + y*sin
            closestRhoIndex = int(round(targetRho))
            countMatrix[closestRhoIndex, thetaIndex] += 1
    lines = [(p,thetaRange[t]) for (p,t), value in np.ndenumerate(countMatrix) if value > threshold]
    return lines
```

It works but it is very slow, 100 times slower than the opencv implementation.

How can I improve it?

Comment: Python code will always be significantly slower than native code. One option is [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org). Also, you should index as `countMatrix[closestRhoIndex, thetaIndex]`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo but that much slower really? I will try numba, and why the index thing? Is it faster that way or just nicer?

Comment: I think the indexing should be faster, but probably not significantly. `countMatrix[closestRhoIndex][thetaIndex]` first does `countMatrix[closestRhoIndex]`, creating a new, intermediate matrix, then indexes into that. Python being 100 times slower is totally expected, yes. This is the difference between an interpreted language and a compiled language.

Comment: A very recent related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54224976/7328782

Comment: Thank you, now I feel less dumb. I'm having trouble with numba but I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use numba. This is what the code looks like now:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def houghLines(edges, dTheta, threshold):
    imageShape = edges.shape
    imageDiameter = (imageShape[0]**2 + imageShape[1]**2)**0.5
    rhoRange = [i for i in range(int(imageDiameter)+1)]
    thetaRange = [dTheta*i for i in range(int(-np.pi/(2*dTheta)), int(np.pi/dTheta))]
    cosTheta = []
    sinTheta = []
    for theta in thetaRange:
        cosTheta.append(np.cos(theta))
        sinTheta.append(np.sin(theta))
    countMatrixSize = (len(rhoRange), len(thetaRange))
    countMatrix = np.zeros(countMatrixSize)

    eds = []
    for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(edges):
        if value > 0:
            eds.append((x,y))

    for thetaIndex in range(len(thetaRange)):
        theta = thetaRange[thetaIndex]
        cos = cosTheta[thetaIndex]
        sin = sinTheta[thetaIndex]
        for x, y in eds:
            targetRho = x*cos + y*sin
            closestRhoIndex = int(round(targetRho))
            countMatrix[closestRhoIndex, thetaIndex] += 1
    lines = []
    for (p,t), value in np.ndenumerate(countMatrix):
        if value > threshold:
            lines.append((p,thetaRange[t]))
    return lines
```

This made it at least 50 times faster.